# Access database from angular component with service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate my combo box from the database on page load. When I debug it, debug point don't hit at adminsService.test(result) at all. Why is that? I am trying to get the data without any conditions.

```
angular.module('adminService', []).factory('adminService', function ($rootScope, $http) {

    var modelService = function () {

    }

    modelService.prototype.test = function (test) {
        var promise = $http(
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Model/getTopics',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {
                test: test
            }
        });

        return promise;

    }

    viewRoleModule.controller('viewRoleController', function ($scope, $routeParams, adminService) {

    var self = this;
    self.$onInit = function () {

        self.topicRoleItems = function ()
        {
            adminService.test(result);
        };
    }
});


<div ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.topicRoleItems">
    {{item.TopicName}}         
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 self.topicRoleItems = adminService.test().then(function(result){
      self.topicRoleItems = result;
 });
```

UPDATE

```
.factory('adminService', function ($rootScope, $http,$q) {

 var modelService = [];

 modelService.test = function (test) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Model/getTopics',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {
            test: test
        }
    }).success(function(resp){
       deferred.resolve(resp);
    }).error(function(resp){
       deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return modelService;
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting the error that: adminService.test  is not a function